# Need steps to be taken to work from India but employed in Germany

Tags: germany, india, insurance

I have a *Niederlassungserlaubnis* and am employed in Germany. The company is remote first currently so working from home is not a problem.

I would like to work from India for 3 months and take a month off after that. So in total would like to stay in India for 4 months.  I will still have my residence here and taxes would be paid as usual. What are the steps I need to take before I leave, so that there are no issues with:

1. Insurance (all)
2. Company